# How do I loop serialize data append in formData sent via AJAX in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, serialization

I use `formData` to sent some data via AJAX.

```
//DATA KANDIDAT
var data_kandidat   = $(".data-kandidat").serializeArray();
                        
//DATA KELUARGA
var data_keluarga   = $(".data-kandidat-keluarga").serialize();
                        
var regist_data     = new FormData();
                      
    regist_data.append("data_kandidat",JSON.stringify(data_kandidat));
    regist_data.append("data_keluarga",data_keluarga);
    regist_data.append("<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>",csrfHash);
                        
    $.ajax({ url         : url,                     
             type        : 'POST',
             data        : regist_data,
             cache       : false,
             contentType : false,                       
             processData : false,
             async       : true,
             dataType    : 'JSON',
             beforeSend  : function(){
                                
                              $("#loading-div").removeAttr("class");
                              $("#loading-div").addClass("overlay overlay-on");
                           }
             })
            .done(function(data){
                            
               alert("SUCCESS");
                            
             })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            
               alert("FAIL");
             });
```

I loop it in PHP Controller:

```
$details     = $this->input->post('data_keluarga');
$ct_keluarga = 0;

foreach($details as $rows ){
            
   $dataadd    = array ( 'KANDIDAT_ID'      => $ins_kandpribadi,
                         'KELUARGA_NAMA'    => $rows['i_keluarga_nama'],
                         'KELUARGA_STATUS'  => $rows['i_keluarga_status'],
                         'KELUARGA_KONTAK'  => $rows['i_keluarga_kontak'],
                         'DIFFERENTIATOR'   => 1,
                         'STATUS'           => 1
                       );

   $ins_kandkeluarga    = $this->model_insert->ins_kandidat_keluarga($dataadd);
            
   $ct_keluarga++;
}
        
$ret_message = $this->input->post('data_keluarga');
```

This is what I get when I check the data retrieved:

```
echo $this->input->post('data_keluarga');
'arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_nama%5D=Rayna&arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_status%5D=Istri&arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_kontak%5D=23523526&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_nama%5D=Anisa&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_status%5D=Anak&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_kontak%5D=121467867';
```

I used above code and somehow the values are not saved in DB. How do I properly loop it? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: do print_r of $details to  share for more clarity ` $details     = $this->input->post('data_keluarga');`

Comment: I would print the value of `$dataadd` before inserting, to make sure you have consistent data

Comment: @Sundar this is the data in controller `'arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_nama%5D=Rayna&arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_status%5D=Istri&arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_kontak%5D=23523526&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_nama%5D=Anisa&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_status%5D=Anak&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_kontak%5D=121467867';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [parse_str(string $string, array &$result)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to unserialized serialized form data

code :-

```
$post_data = "arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_nama%5D=Rayna&arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_status%5D=Istri&arr_keluarga%5B0%5D%5Bi_keluarga_kontak%5D=23523526&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_nama%5D=Anisa&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_status%5D=Anak&arr_keluarga%5B1%5D%5Bi_keluarga_kontak%5D=121467867";

$data_array = array();
parse_str($post_data,$data_array);

var_dump($data_array);
```

result

```
array(1) {
  ["arr_keluarga"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["i_keluarga_nama"]=>
      string(5) "Rayna"
      ["i_keluarga_status"]=>
      string(5) "Istri"
      ["i_keluarga_kontak"]=>
      string(8) "23523526"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["i_keluarga_nama"]=>
      string(5) "Anisa"
      ["i_keluarga_status"]=>
      string(4) "Anak"
      ["i_keluarga_kontak"]=>
      string(9) "121467867"
    }
  }
}
```